# Does including the no cache meta tag in an html file also prevent the js and css files linked in that html file from being cached?

Tags: javascript, html, css, caching, meta-tags

I have written the no-cache meta tags in html files. Does this only prevent the html file from being cached, or also the js and css files linked in that html file?

Answer (score 0):

There are bugs in both Netscape Navigator (NN) and Internet Explorer (IE).If you only use:

`<META HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">`

You should also add:

`<META HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="-1">`